# Wildcard of Number Ranges in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, range

The pattern match in sql server doesn't work like regex. Is it possible to use LIKE to match number ranges? I need to do something like this:

```
ABCD 1
ABCD 2
ABCD 3
ABCD 4
ABCD 8
ABCD 9
ABCD 10
...
ABCD 20
```

I want to select all data from "ABCD 1" to "ABCD 20". But I want to ignore anything between "ABCD 4" and "ABCD 8". Of course I can do OR conditions, but I just want to check if there is more elegant way.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) operator and specify your pattern executing a query like this one:

```
SELECT mydata FROM mytable
WHERE(mydata LIKE 'ABCD [1-9]' OR mydata LIKE 'ABCD 1[0-9]' OR mydata LIKE 'ABCD 20') 
AND mydata NOT LIKE 'ABCD [4-8]';
```

or, something more concise and shorter:

```
SELECT mydata FROM mytable
where mydata like 'ABCD [^4-8]%';
```

Have a look at [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94d5f/1).

Comment: Hi Alberto, thank you and others to spend time in answering my questions. Your answer is very similar to my approach, but I have one less OR;). I thought there might be more concise way to tackle this. Btw, why would someone dislike my question???

Comment: @user516221 Yes, I found a better way to handle your patterns. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use like in SQL Server like this:

```
where col like 'ABCD [1-9]' or
      col like 'ABCD 1[0-9]' or
      col like 'ABCD 20'
```

Comment: Seems too long but it works while others don't. And is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename
where cast(replace(somecolumn, 'ABCD','') as numeric) < 4
and cast(replace(somecolumn, 'ABCD','') as numeric) > 8
```